# Touch pad not working on Lenovo ThinkBook 14-IML

Tags: lenovo, system-settings

Apparently Ubuntu has some problems with the kernel integration and more modern hardware. We installed these operating systems: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Ubuntu 19.10, Ubuntu 20.04, and also CentOS 8.1.1911, but the touch pad does not work on this Lenovo ThinkBook 14-IML.

We tried kernel version updating, and Gnome Tweaks ukku installed in Tweaks also checked all the settings.

Twice cross checked Synaptics installed or no improvement.

- xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
- installation done after that also no improvement.
- ukuu --install-latest also done (Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility)
- Upgrading the kernel to versions 5.5 and 5.5.7 using UKUU, which did not solve the problem.
- We checked all firmware updates available that also couldn't succeed.

We tried all possibilities and couldn't succeed.

How may we troubleshoot this further to solve the touchpad failure?

Comment: have you tried: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection

Comment: @Gryu Seems OP accidentally used flags instead of comments.  Their response is "We tried but couldn't succeed." (from the declined flags)

Comment: Please open a terminal window and run `lsusb -v` then highlight the text, copy the text, then return here and click [edit]. Paste the results into the question so we can see more detail on that laptop's hardware. Please do not use Add Comment.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Ubuntu on my Lenovo Thinkbook 15 IML and experienced exactly the same problem. Lenovo did not provide a solution for this "simple" task. As you mentioned, it is not rocket science and solution should have been provided by Lenovo Support Team since it is a basic functionality that should be guaranteed to work on any OS.

Anyway, Ubuntu community and its helpers are pretty amazing. After a few months struggling with the problem, Kai Heng-Feng found a solution and provided a test kernel which solved the issue. Now my Touchpad is working.

You can apply the test kernel published in comment #88 in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1853277

To apply this kernel you should download it and then go to Download folder and write the following sentence on a terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-image-5.9.0-rc4+_5.9.0-rc4+-4_amd64.deb
```

Restart your computer, and enjoy your working Touchpad!

P.S.: I believe this solution works for a Lenovo Thinkbook IIL series as well. Maybe the permanent solution will be published in a future Ubuntu official kernel.