# Lenovo-ThinkBook-14-IIL Touchpad not working

Tags: drivers, touchpad, lenovo

How can I fix this? The solutions suggested in [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1215236/touch-pad-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkbook-14-iml) and [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245632/lenovo-thinkbook-iml-touchpad-not-recognized) did not work for me.

The only device that looks like it could be my trackpad is this one `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`:

```
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Ideapad extra buttons"
P: Phys=ideapad/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/VPC2004:00/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event5 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=81000800100c03 4400000000300000 0 2
B: MSC=10
```

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Touchpad worked under Windwos.

Comment: It means that the touchpad is not supported by Linux yet.

Comment: fuck. What can I do? Is there anything?

Comment: perhaps you try the answer i provided for your second link - even though it is a differnet model you might be lucky and they used the same touchpad ;)

Comment: found something: maybe that works ;) https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Ubuntu/ThinkBook-14-IML-ELAN-TouchPad-Not-Recognized-Ubuntu/m-p/4622518?page=2#5072125

Comment: Did not work for bios `DJCN16WW` and kernel `5.4.0-37-generic`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My touchpad is working now. I am not sure what happened. I guess this fix came with a software update? How do I know with which update this came?

System Information

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

`cat /proc/bus/input/devices` now also lists the `Elan Touchpad`

```
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=04f3 Product=005b Version=0000
N: Name="Elan Touchpad"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-0/i2c-ELAN0634:00/input/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event7 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=663800013000003
```

Answer (score 2):

We were also facing the same problem with Lenovo ThinkBool-14IIL, We just update the kernel as per the below link and the touchpad start working for us with the latest bios version.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1853277

Try your luck with this. and if it works, do not forget to say thanks to Kai.

Answer (score 2):

Appending "i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs" to boot parameters worked for the touchpad issue on the Lenovo V14-IIL.

Following are the steps I've followed:

1.) Open the file /etc/default/grub for editing, for example by running

sudoedit /etc/default/grub

2.) Add to the line beginning GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT: "i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs" so that it reads:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs"

** If other parameters are there between the double quotes, it may be OK to leave them.

3.) Save the file and exit

4.) Run this command to update the GRUB configuration:

sudo update-grub

5.) Reboot

Other relevant threads for this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1881322/comments/5
[ELAN Touchpad not working on Lenovo IdeaPad with Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206190/elan-touchpad-not-working-on-lenovo-ideapad-with-ubuntu-16-04)
https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Ubuntu/ThinkBook-14-IML-ELAN-TouchPad-Not-Recognized-Ubuntu/m-p/4622518?page=2#5104555

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1861610/comments/66
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1861610/comments/96

Comment: This worked for me..Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the laptops BIOS.  You can fix the acpi tables by following comment 66 and 96 in this ubuntu bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1861610/

Comment: [Edit] and include the relevant parts of the link in your answer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Lenovo 14-IIL and Kubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.7.5-050705-generic. The solution was installing the newest kernel;  I tried the HW enablement version ("HWE") as it should have the newest possible HW drivers and it worked. Here is the command that I used for installing it:

```
apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04
```

After reboot, the touchpad started working. For reference, it installed this kernel version:

```
5.15.0-76-generic #83~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 21 20:23:31 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```